# The LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is not recognized by the target C# executable's runtime environment

Tags: ubuntu, c++, mono

I tested this C++ program on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 yesterday. What bothers me is 
the fact that the following program starts a mono-service programmatically which I see in the Ubuntu 16.04 /var/log/syslog file but fails to pass the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the C# executable's runtime environment even though I
pass an envp pointer to the `execve` system call. The way I can tell that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is not recognized by the target executable's runtime environment, is that the target executable is misbehaving 
and skipping all functions where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` tells where to find the runtime library dependencies.

```
#include <unistd.h>     // execv(), fork()
#include <sys/types.h>  // pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h>   // waitpid()
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argvp)
{
   char *argv[] = { "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe",
                    "Audio_Video_Recorder.exe", 0};


    char *envp[] =
    {
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.",
        0
    };
    execve(argv[0], &argv[0], envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
    return -1;

}
```

Is is possible to fix this oversight programmatically using C++ and the Linux API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being Debian/Ubuntu based, it's not likely that the problem is due to rpath (still possible).  More likely you're getting into trouble with

```
"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=."
```

which doesn't provide an absolute pathname.

You can use `strace` to show which paths the executable tries to open, e.g.,

```
strace -f -o strace.log mono myprogram
```

and look for the "open" calls.

In principle, you can run `ldd` on any shared executable on Linux, e.g.,

```
ldd myprogram
```

or (probably)

```
ldd /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe
```

Likewise, objdump gives useful information, e.g.,

```
objdump -ax /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe
```

to see whether any of the shared libraries are resolved via absolute pathnames.  obdump would should that in the section (of its output) "Dynamic libraries".

However, the comments in *[Equivalent of ldd for .NET/Mono Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397492/equivalent-of-ldd-for-net-mono-applications)* indicate that you may need a higher-level (and different tool) to get useful information, e.g., by setting an environment variable;

```
$ MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono myprogram
```

Further reading:

- [Mono notes](http://pervasive.etl.luc.edu/operating-systems/openwrt/mono)

Comment: Thank you for your very nice answer just now. You mention that the problem may still be due to rpath. I thought rpath applied to c++ executables only  . In my case , Audio_Video_Recorder.exe is a C# .NET executable which has a DLLImport to AudioControlLibrary64.so, which is an C++ shared object. How might I adapt the rpath solution to a C# executable  which needs to be run as a mono-service? I did try the absolute LD_LIBRARY_PATH pathname yesterday and it did not seem to make a difference . I will try it again in 10 minutes and report back to this thread.

Comment: rpath is a feature that is used to enforce locations (absolute or relative) of shared libraries versus executables.  You can see if mono uses this by looking at output from `ldd` or `objdump`.  I mentioned it because mono is *supposed* to run in a restricted environment...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I find the dependencies of a C# .NET executable with ldd or objdump or readelf? In addition, How might we use th rpath feature in my scenario?

Comment: I just tried "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/seattle/Debug" with an absolute pathname. How might I check if  my implementation of execve with L_LIBRARY_PATH pathname is correct? Thank you.

Comment: If you're looking for shared libraries, using strace.  If you're looking to see mono resolve assemblies, using the environment variable `MONO_LOG_LEVEL` (ttyl)